# What assumptions must be satisfied to use R^2 to compute the F statistic?

Tags: r-squared, assumptions, f-test

Suppose I know R^2 for my symbolic regression.  Can I use the formula $F = \frac{R^2}{1-R^2}\cdot \frac{n-p}{p-1}$ to do an F test?

My symbolic regression is of the form
Y = a + bf(A,B,C,D,E,G) + cg(A,B,C,D,E,G) + dh(A,B,C,D,E,G) + error term, where the functions f(), g(), and h() are nonlinear products like A*(C^2)*D*E*(G^3).

Do I need to perform statistical tests to ensure that certain assumptions are satisfied, and if so what are those tests?  What might be the consequence of not doing those tests?

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: Could you explain what hypothesis you want to test? E.g. do you want to compare your model to a constant model, test for inclusion of certain terms, ... ?

Comment: At this stage, I would like to compare the model returned by genetic programming/symbolic regression to the constant model.                         Eventually I would like to test whether the model produced when using that variable as a building block has a better fit than the model produced when the algorithm wasn't allowed to use that variable as a building block.

Comment: Above I meant to write "when using a Certain variable" instead of "when using that variable."

Comment: @Richard Hardy May I please ask you to take a look at this question? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I do not think I can answer it on the spot, and I am in a bit of a time crunch otherwise.